# Call action when user presses key other than 'enter' or 'return'

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I know that it is quite simple to call a function when a user presses the 'return' key on a keyboard, but I was wondering if something similar would be possible with any other key. In my case specifically, I would like to know when a user presses the 'comma'. I am trying to achieve functionality that looks something like what Mail on mac does in the address bar, where if you type a comma the text changes into a different view.

This is what I am referencing:
[image]
[image]

Comment: so you want to call a method when you press comma for first time or for every time ?

Comment: I would like to call the method every time the comma is pressed.

Comment: why dont you use shouldchange charcatersInRange method for that purpose?

Comment: That method triggers for every press on keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method:

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if ([string isEqualToString:@","]||[string containsString:@","]) {

        NSLog(@"trigger method"); //call your method
    }

    return YES;
}
```

For Swift:

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
if string.isEqualToString(",") || string.containsString(",") {
    NSLog("trigger method")
}
return true
}
```

Note: Dont forget to set the text field delegate and mention **UITextFieldDelegate**  at your interface.

```
self.textField.delegate=self;
```

So every time you press comma, you can call your method.As @rmaddy suggested, if user pasted a comma character or any text that has comma in it, then also this  method triggers a call to your own method.

Comment: Could you add the Swift version?

Comment: @Acoop If you don't want Objective-C code, why did you tag the question with [objective-c]?

Comment: Keep in mind that the user can paste in a bunch of text besides typing on the keyboard. The logic in this answer may (or may not) need to deal with that.

Comment: @Mr.T My point was that someone might paste the text `"One, two"`, for example. How should that comma be dealt with? The simple check to see if `string` is equal to `","` won't work in that case.

Comment: I am trying to use the method you suggested but it does not seem to be getting called the I type into the text field.

Comment: you have to set the delegate for your textfield. I updated my answer @Acoop

Comment: how did you set the delegate? to the view controller ?

Comment: you need to set the delegate of textfield to the view controller

Comment: I did exactly this. I just tried the `shouldChangeTextInRange` and it worked exactly as you said `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` would work.